How to fix "error on loading data from the server getit12new.embarcadero.com" when downloading RAD Studio 12.0
I download RAD Studio 12.0 and activated the trial with the license key, but I'm encountering an error:

I read this which says:

The servers are down at the moment and you need to use the offline installer. This has been going on for about a week now.

How do I use the offline installer for when the servers are down?

You'll need to email Embarcadero as they'l most likely be able to answer your question.

The description you found on Reddit is for a different issue that was resolved weeks ago. This is a new problem.

Are you aware that 12.1 is available now? Do you have the same problem with it?

An Embarcadero insider tells me that "GetIt is not down AFAIK. I just checked and 11 and 12 are both working normally... GetItNow and blogs are both having some work done on them so they might be a little shaky but operational." It has been hours since you first posted this, are you still getting the same error?

Generally such questions are in domain of customer support and are off topic for Stack Overflow. We cannot solve issues with intermittent website problems. You should contact Embarcadero support https://www.embarcadero.com/support

@DalijaPrasnikar Since there seems to be an 'alternative' that can bypass the temporary error, I have modified the question to ask about the alternative, to make the question more broadly applicable.

just had the same problem with Delphi 12.2 online installer. However it works fine with ISO version. Just takes some more upfront  downloading :)
